# How to query nested josn structure in mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb, nested-lists

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['AnalyzeMEdb']
collection = db['counters']


json_object = {
   "82188999": {
      "collector_P_172.16.0.55_13Sep2023_12_08": {
         "newnslog": {
            "tcp_tot_txMbits": [
               {
                  "value": 902130,
                  "rate": 0,
                  "Time": "Sep 13 04:59:52 2023"
               },
               {
                  "value": 902132,
                  "rate": 0,
                  "Time": "Sep 13 04:59:59 2023"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
collection.insert_one(json_object)
```

This is how I have inserted data into Mongodb.

Now I want a query which will give me all the elements in **tcp_tot_txMbits** array

I have tired this

```
results = collection.find({ "82188999.collector_P_172.16.0.55_13Sep2023_12_08.newnslog.tcp_tot_txMbits": { "$exists": True } })
```

but I am getting none as a result.

Can you help me with a correct query?

Comment: Hey! So I'm pretty sure this happens because of the `.` in your collector field, you'd need to escape these. Maybe try escaping like this `results = collection.find({ "82188999.collector_P_172\.16\.0\.55_13Sep2023_12_08.newnslog.tcp_tot_txMbits": { "$exists": True } })` (not sure it works)
`

Comment: or maybe `results = collection.find({
    '"82188999"."collector_P_172.16.0.55_13Sep2023_12_08.newnslog.tcp_tot_txMbits"': {
        '$exists': True
    }
})`

Comment: That is a good catch, but still I am not getting the result. It is returning NULL

Comment: I meant `results = collection.find({     '"82188999"."collector_P_172.16.0.55_13Sep2023_12_08"."newnslog"."tcp_tot_txMbits"': {         '$exists': True     } })` sry

Comment: I tried this already, it is not working for me. @AchilleG did this work for you?